# Hazelcast Embedded mode - How to connect to the cluster and retrieve a map from a node that is part of the cluster?

Tags: java, hazelcast

I have a hazelcast embedded cluster of two nodes. I can access a map in the cluster if i go about using a HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient() instance but i am not able to get the same results if i use the Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(). If i manipulate the map from one node, the other node works on a totally different map ; the changes arent there.

Is it a requirement that i should use a HazelcastClient instance to connect to an embedded hazelcast cluster. It seems unnecessary to create and configure clients (hazelcast-client.xml) in embedded mode when you have the actual cluster instance object available.

EDIT:- The discovery mechanism used is TCP.

Setup shown below has two simple java WAR files running on two different tomcats running on the same machine. I make them discoverable via the TCP discovery mechanism as shown below.

hazelcast.xml ( top part only )

```
<hazelcast xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config hazelcast-config-3.9.xsd"
           xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <group>
        <name>dev</name>
        <password>dev-pass</password>
    </group>
    <management-center enabled="false">http://localhost:8080/mancenter</management-center>
    <properties>
        <property name="hazelcast.discovery.enabled">true</property>
    </properties>
    <network>
        <port auto-increment="true" port-count="100">5701</port>
        <outbound-ports>
            <ports>5700-6750</ports>
        </outbound-ports>
        <join>
            <multicast enabled="false">
                <multicast-group>224.2.2.3</multicast-group>
                <multicast-port>54327</multicast-port>
            </multicast>



            <tcp-ip enabled="true">
                <member-list>
                    <member>127.0.0.1:5701</member>
                    <member>127.0.0.1:5702</member>
                </member-list>
            </tcp-ip>
```

Log Output ( from node 1 )

```
STARTING UP INSTANCE...
Apr 09, 2018 5:26:40 PM com.hazelcast.config.XmlConfigLocator
INFO: Loading 'hazelcast.xml' from classpath.
Apr 09, 2018 5:26:40 PM com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker
INFO: [LOCAL] [dev] [3.9.3] Interfaces is disabled, trying to pick one address from TCP-IP config addresses: [127.0.0.1]
Apr 09, 2018 5:26:40 PM com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker
INFO: [LOCAL] [dev] [3.9.3] Picked [127.0.0.1]:5701, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,localport=5701], bind any local is true
Apr 09, 2018 5:26:40 PM com.hazelcast.system
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.9.3] Hazelcast 3.9.3 (20180216 - 539b124) starting at [127.0.0.1]:5701
Apr 09, 2018 5:26:40 PM com.hazelcast.system
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.9.3] Copyright (c) 2008-2018, Hazelcast, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Apr 09, 2018 5:26:40 PM com.hazelcast.system
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.9.3] Configured Hazelcast Serialization version: 1
Apr 09, 2018 5:26:40 PM com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.BackpressureRegulator
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.9.3] Backpressure is disabled
Apr 09, 2018 5:26:41 PM com.hazelcast.instance.Node
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.9.3] Activating Discovery SPI Joiner
Apr 09, 2018 5:26:41 PM com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.9.3] Starting 8 partition threads and 5 generic threads (1 dedicated for priority tasks)
Apr 09, 2018 5:26:41 PM com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.Diagnostics
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.9.3] Diagnostics disabled. To enable add -Dhazelcast.diagnostics.enabled=true to the JVM arguments.
Apr 09, 2018 5:26:41 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.9.3] [127.0.0.1]:5701 is STARTING
09-Apr-2018 17:26:46.770 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/Users/cheni04/lac/workspace/DeveloperSetup/Servers/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.24/webapps/manager]
09-Apr-2018 17:26:46.819 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/Users/cheni04/lac/workspace/DeveloperSetup/Servers/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.24/webapps/manager] has finished in [48] ms
Apr 09, 2018 5:26:46 PM com.hazelcast.system
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.9.3] Cluster version set to 3.9
Apr 09, 2018 5:26:46 PM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.ClusterService
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.9.3] 

Members {size:1, ver:1} [
    Member [127.0.0.1]:5701 - b011dd1b-675d-4176-ad7e-839fd813eaed this
]

The number for this node is :1
Apr 09, 2018 5:26:46 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
```

Log Output ( from node 2 )

```
STARTING UP INSTANCE...
Apr 09, 2018 5:27:12 PM com.hazelcast.config.XmlConfigLocator
INFO: Loading 'hazelcast.xml' from classpath.
Apr 09, 2018 5:27:12 PM com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker
INFO: [LOCAL] [dev] [3.9.3] Interfaces is disabled, trying to pick one address from TCP-IP config addresses: [127.0.0.1]
Apr 09, 2018 5:27:12 PM com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker
INFO: [LOCAL] [dev] [3.9.3] Picked [127.0.0.1]:5702, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,localport=5702], bind any local is true
Apr 09, 2018 5:27:12 PM com.hazelcast.system
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.9.3] Hazelcast 3.9.3 (20180216 - 539b124) starting at [127.0.0.1]:5702
Apr 09, 2018 5:27:12 PM com.hazelcast.system
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.9.3] Copyright (c) 2008-2018, Hazelcast, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Apr 09, 2018 5:27:12 PM com.hazelcast.system
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.9.3] Configured Hazelcast Serialization version: 1
Apr 09, 2018 5:27:13 PM com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.BackpressureRegulator
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.9.3] Backpressure is disabled
Apr 09, 2018 5:27:14 PM com.hazelcast.instance.Node
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.9.3] Activating Discovery SPI Joiner
Apr 09, 2018 5:27:14 PM com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.9.3] Starting 8 partition threads and 5 generic threads (1 dedicated for priority tasks)
Apr 09, 2018 5:27:14 PM com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.Diagnostics
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.9.3] Diagnostics disabled. To enable add -Dhazelcast.diagnostics.enabled=true to the JVM arguments.
Apr 09, 2018 5:27:14 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.9.3] [127.0.0.1]:5702 is STARTING
Apr 09, 2018 5:27:19 PM com.hazelcast.system
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.9.3] Cluster version set to 3.9
Apr 09, 2018 5:27:19 PM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.ClusterService
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.9.3] 

Members {size:1, ver:1} [
    Member [127.0.0.1]:5702 - 4c7d74d6-0c13-4142-807b-48ab57fd7981 this
]

Apr 09, 2018 5:27:19 PM com.hazelcast.instance.Node
WARNING: [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.9.3] Config seed port is 5701 and cluster size is 1. Some of the ports seem occupied!
Apr 09, 2018 5:27:19 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
The number for this node is :1
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.9.3] [127.0.0.1]:5702 is STARTED
```

Comment: Are you able to post the logs from both nodes ? If they have successfully clustered together then the same map content should be accessible from either. If it's not, then that suggests they haven't joined and what you have instead is two unique maps, one per node, in two one-node clusters. The thing to look for is the `Members {size:1, ver:1} [` line in the logs where the size listed counts the number of server instances. This will start at 1 but should rise to 2 if the second node succeeds in joining - it may be rejected, eg. if it has different credentials

Comment: It doesnt add both node IPs as members in the both instances. But the map seem to be shared when i use a client instance.

Comment: Are you able to post the logs from both nodes ?

Comment: Did you solve the problem ?

Comment: Not yet. I will update the question with config.xml and logs shortly.

Comment: Have the logs added. Clearly it doesnt seem to detect the node.

Comment: The range for inbound ports and outbound ports overlap. Can you make them distinct please and retry ? Inbound is 5701 for 100, `<port auto-increment="true" port-count="100">5701</port>` outbound `<ports>5700-6750</ports>`. Try changing the latter to `<ports>5900-6750</ports>` for example

Comment: That did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `<property name="hazelcast.discovery.enabled">true</property>`

Change this to `<property name="hazelcast.discovery.enabled">false</property>` or remove it, and all should be ok

This property is mainly intended for activation of custom discovery plugins (for Kubernetes, Eureka, etc) instead of the built-ins such as TCP or Multicast.
You want TCP here.